# Execute a method in a different .net framework version

Tags: c#, .net, com, clr

I'm using a third-party COM object that for some reason only work with .NET versions 2.0 - 3.5.
Trying to use it in a higher version causing few of the methods in this dll to break.
My console application is based on .NET 4.0 and I don't want to downgrade in order to make it work.

I already tried solutions like adding older version support in the app.config like the following but it doesn't work:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
</startup>
```

It's only a guess but I think it has something to do with the CLR version changed between 2.0 - 3.5 and 4.0.

Is there any way to execute a method from a .NET 4.0 console application in the context of .NET 2.0 that will use this COM object?

Comment: It is possible for a process to host both CLRv2 and CLRv4 runtimes at the same time, where each runtime will see the other as native code. I have not tried it myself so I can't really give details, but [David Broman](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2010/08/25/profilers-in-process-side-by-side-clr-instances-and-a-free-test-harness.aspx) has a blog that discusses it in the context of profiler development (he provided a 'free test harness' that probably could have served as an example but that link appears to be dead).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know of to do something like this would be to create a separate project that uses .NET 2.0 and makes the needed calls. E.g.

[image: .NET 4 console app references .NET 2 library project]

Comment: Hi @tim-s I already tried that, it does not work.
the secondary project runs as .NET 4 in case that  console is configures as .NET 4.
try running:   System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetSystemVersion() and see the result.